# Trouble integrating FB login into my android app

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

recently i have made an android app which integrating facebook login. It works fine when i login with my FB account which is also setup as a FB developer account(where i kept my app release key and debug key).But problem is that when i want to login with other FB account for testing it show me error like this

```
App Not Setup. The developers of this app have not srt up
this app properly for Facebook Login.
```

i follow this tutorial https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/authenticate   it works fine as they showed with my developer FB ac.But why not with other FB account? What else i should do to make this app available to other user? Please give me suggestion ...please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to turn the app on for general use - I dont exactly remember where in the FB Dev Console - Google!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to your facebook developer console and select your project(app) from app section.Then in status and review turn on the option--Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?.
You will need an email id to turn it on so add one if you haven't already.